# Сортировка слиянием

Tags: сортировка

У кого-нибудь есть идеи, как сделать сортировку слиянием не рекурсией, а итерацией?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой вариант:

- Поделить на масссивы по одному элементу и положить их в очередь.
- Извлечь из очереди два элемента, слить в один и положить обратно в очередь
- Повторять пока в очереди не останется 1 элемент

Comment: Да да, точно, как же я забыл про очередь) Спасибо!